# PHP opening link from Excel runs page three times

Tags: php

I'm having a strange issue, which I find difficult to summarize in a title.

**First:**

- I have a webpage, where people need to be logged in.
- I have a Excel document, with links to the webpage.

**The problem:**
When people are logged in, and they click on the link in the Excel document. The webpage tells them that they are not logged in.

**What I found so far:**

- I'm using Office on Mac and I **don't** have any issues.
- People using Office on Windows **do** have issues.
- I think the issue is due to `SESSIONS`, that might be the reason why users aren't logged in while they should be.

I did some tests.

Every URL goes through index.php

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
file_put_contents('log.txt', microtime().': SERVER '.print_r($_SERVER, true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
exit;
```

Now when I click the link from Office on Mac (NO ISSUES!!!), I get a dump of the variable `$_SERVER`. Two important variables:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=77lpqmdmvskv33d2ddsdlfs5q7; rememberme=1%3Ae79e92271e7e05a5ee5679b659b3cb5cbb61e60d96c158f4648960136b175164%3Accdee80c3e42705fcd7e8c234525beda86d27394653dfdfb42bdd3ec98592ca1
```

You can see the browser (Chrome) and the cookie, which contains a `rememberme` cookie for login.

Now, when I do the same by clicking on a link in Excel on Windows, I get the `$_SERVER` variable printed three times in the log file!

First:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Microsoft Office Excel 2014
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=0ivlfjf49j4b82858tstc2lmm3; PHPSESSID=tv6gs33j721d0tmm3rrjdoho45
```

Notice the user agent and no rememberme cookie.

Second:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; ms-office)
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=0ivlfjf49j4b82858tstc2lmm3
```

Notice, still no chrome browser and rememberme cookie.

Third:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=3s0hvtssghk7uomvkpb5k70tc2; rememberme=1%3Aa9bd74ad58a0d7075c27108be1adbd26ba6d18f6e8b39073152d6780131ffe70%3A643852f8636c76c0bfc4017ec7fe3eab98dd57f5bcfdf86f0e37b5ec28a0c0ef
```

Finally user agent is Chrome and rememberme cookie is set.

So, it's getting a long story. But clicking on the link in Excel from Windows, it does strange things. Anyone an idea what is happening?

Comment: OK, I found this issue, seems to be the same problem I'm having! http://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug

Answer (score 1):

Oke, I found the problem. Below an answer from superuser.com

> The URL you're using needs some more information from a cookie to
>   display the search results rather than the search page. Paste the URL
>   into a different browser (or remove your cookies) and you'll get the
>   same results.
>
> Clicking a URL in Excel seems to open it in your default browser. But
>   that's not really true. Before opening it in your browser, Excel first
>   runs Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery. This uses a Windows/Internet
>   Explorer component to determine if the URL works. (It does not
>   identify itself as Internet Explorer, but as "User Agent: Microsoft
>   Office Existence Discovery".) And if the results are (somehow) okay
>   then it will open the result of that check in your default browser.
>
> Lacking the cookies (more precisely: lacking a session), GoDaddy gives
>   that Internet Explorer component some redirect. And the result of that
>   is opened in your default browser. That's the URL you're seeing.
>
> Most likely your default browser is not Internet Explorer? Then
>   pasting the URL into IE directly and clicking it, to get the cookies,
>   might then also make the link work from Excel. (Just for testing; it's
>   not a permanent solution.)
>
> You will have more luck using a URL that does not rely on some hidden
>   information from a cookie, like
>   http://www.godaddy.com/domains/search.aspx?domainToCheck=superuser.com

Source: https://superuser.com/a/445431

So to solve this issue:
When Excel checked the link, it gets redirected to '/login' because it wasn't logged in. And finally that URL is the URL Excel opens in the real browser.

So I changed the login script and a user will not be redirected to '/login', but stay on the same URL and it will be shown the login form if not logged in. Excel now opens the original URL an if the user is logged in, it will see the page. If it is not logged in, the login form will be shown.